# Android RecyclerView item dynamic layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

Inside my recycler view item layout I want to add something like horizontal recyclerview layout, because I don't know how many ImageViews I need, that's why I can't create them as a static layout. The number of icons depends on server logic. How can achieve something like the picutre below ?
Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Need Add Horizontal Recyclerview Inside The Main Recyclerview.
Your First RecyclerView is Verticle list and inside every index create another RecyclerView It's a Horizontal. so you can display n number of Imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Recyclerview inside the child layout of your main Recyclerview

Something like

Suppose this is the Main Recyclerview

```
     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_demo" />
```

In your child layout, Let's say `item_demo` you have to add another Recyclerview for the imageView that you want to show in horizontal

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        tools:listitem="@layout/item_child" />
```

`item_child` layout contains the Imageview that will display horizontally